# Need Help Grouping in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code to group payment amount by Invoice Number and

- If Type 1 or 2 I want to Display the `sum(Amount)` as `Interest`,
- If Type 3 or 4 I want to Display the `sum(Amount)` as `Principal`

I tried the following code to Group by `InvoiceNumber` as shown below but i get `InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression GroupByShaperExpression'` exception.

I want to accomplish

```
 Type       Amount    InvoiceNumber
 1                 $100       123
 2                 $50        123
 3                 $100       123
 4                 $1200      123
 1                 $100       124
 1                 $300       124
 3                 $100       124
 3                 $300       124
 4                 $100       124
```

I want to group by invoice Number and Sum the value of Amount field for Type = 1&2 and display as Interest and 3&4 as Princepal

```
InvoiceNumber       Interest   Princepal
123                 $150        $1300
124                 $400        $500
```

Comment: Please provide the full exception message. It is truncated

Comment: @NineBerry I just updated it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

- EF Core cannot access navigation properties after `GroupBy`
- Even if EF Core could translate this query, it would be ineffective.

Consider to rewrite the query in the following way:

```cs
var ProductPaymentIDs = ProductPayments.Select(pp => pp.ID).ToList();

var query =
    from cl in Context.PaymentCodingLines
    where ProductPaymentIDs.Contains(cl.ProductPaymentID)
    group new { cl.InvoiceLineNav.TypeID, cl.Amount } by g.InvoiceLineNav.InvoiceNav.InvoiceNumber into g
    select new DetailDTO
    {
        InvoiceNumber = g.Key,
        InterestPaid = g.Sum(x => x.TypeID == 1 || x.TypeID == 2 ? x.Amount : 0),
        PrincipalPaid = g.Sum(x => x.TypeID == 3 || x.TypeID == 4 ? x.Amount : 0)
    };

var Details = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for edit.

Comment: Thank you. Works as i expected to work. Thank you for your help!!